# C# Error "Specific cast is not valid." even when verified that it IS valid by checking that objectToCast is ExpectedType

Tags: c#, validation, reflection, casting, type-conversion

Basically, here is what I am doing in code (generic names substituted).

```
Type fooObjType = fooObj.GetType();
PropertyInfo fooProp = fooObjType.GetProperty("FooProperty");
if (fooProp == null || !fooProp.CanRead || !fooProp.CanWrite)
    return;

var fooVal = fooProp.GetValue(fooObj); //<-- Also tried using "object" instead of "var" here.
long longVal = 0;
if (fooVal is long || fooVal is int || fooVal is short)
    longVal = (long)fooVal;//<-- Error on this cast.
//More code for checking if fooVal is Nullable and has a value, and assigning it appropriately for those cases.
```

As you can see, I VERY specifically check that fooVal IS INDEED a type that is castable (implicitly no less) to long, yet c# continues to whine about "Specific cast is not valid.".

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What is entVal?  You're attempting to cast longVal to it, but it isn't defined in any of the code posted

Comment: sry, missed that one from when I was changing names after copy-paste. Edited to better reflect my code. entVal corrected to fooVal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Convert to construct (although I am not sure why entVal is used and not fooVal).
    Convert.ToInt64(entVal)